# How can I get multiple lines using custom summary?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I can get the sum by one choice in the combo box. But I want to print the sum of each of several items.

After selecting an item and entering a value, the input values of all items are added.

How can I fix it?

Like Below Image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTKzv.png)

```
private void gridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    GridView view = sender as GridView;
    exchangeModel = new ExchangeModel();
    exchangeModel.CurrencyName = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("CurrencyName").ToString();
    exchangeModel.Amount = Convert.ToInt32(view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Amount").ToString());
}

private void gridView_CustomSummaryCalculate(object sender, CustomSummaryEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SummaryProcess == CustomSummaryProcess.Start)
    {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<decimal>>();
    }

    if (e.SummaryProcess == CustomSummaryProcess.Calculate)
    {
        string currencyName = e.GetValue("CurrencyName").ToString();
        List<decimal> list;

        if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(currencyName, out list))
        {
            list = new List<decimal>();
            dictionary.Add(currencyName, list);
        }

        list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(e.GetValue("Amount")));
    }

    if (e.SummaryProcess == CustomSummaryProcess.Finalize)
    {
        e.TotalValue = CalculateTotal();
    }
}

private object CalculateTotal()
{
    decimal sum = 0;
    IEnumerator enumerator = dictionary.GetEnumerator();
    enumerator.Reset();

    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        KeyValuePair<string, List<decimal>> current = ((KeyValuePair<string, List<decimal>>)enumerator.Current);

        for (int i = 0; i < current.Value.Count; i++)
        {
            sum += current.Value[i];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you add a few custom summaries to a column using an approach similar to the one illustrated in the **Example** section of the [GridColumn.Summary](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn.Summary) property's description. After that, identify each summary based on **CustomSummaryCalculate**'s **e.Item** parameter and assign required values to e.TotalValue.

**See also:**

[Summaries](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3502/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/summaries)